# Docusign TSP API

Tags: docusignapi

I have applied for the Docusign TSP Program.
We are following these instructions but we are facing some issues.
https://developers.docusign.com/id-tsp-api/guides/tsp-authentication

When we invoke the following route:

```
POST /oauth/token

POST oauth/token HTTP/1.1

Host: account-d.docusign.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50SWQ6Y2xpZW50U2VjcmV0

grant_type=authorization_code
    &code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb

This should be the response that we are expecting:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
{
  "access_token": "(access token example removed for document brevity)",
  "expires_in": 28800,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "user_api": "https://{server}.docusign.net"
}
```

Unfortunately we aren't receiving "user_api", instead we are receiving this:

```
{
  "access_token": "ISSUED_ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "ISSUED_REFRESH_TOKEN",
  "expires_in": 28800
}
```

Are you able to help me?

Comment: Not sure why you're not getting the `user_api` key but another way you **may** be able to get it is with `https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`, that responses with a `base_uri`. Could be that it's the same value since it's tied to the user's account.

Comment: Hi,

I guess that api won't help me, TSP API expects something like /restapi/{version}/signature/ as the base path and this route gives me /restapi/{version}/accounts/{account_id}, which is the base path for the eSignature API. By the way, I should receive that TSP API base route path through the access token request, in the _user_api_ field.

Comment: what do you use for {server}.docusign.net? what URL?